# velocity animations not working in appgyver framework

Tags: android, steroids, velocity.js, appgyver, supersonic

Velocity js is not working in my appgyver app in android, what should I do? I have included nececcery things but still no point, is it even possible to work with velocity animations in cross platfrom applications build with appgyver?

```
<script > 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dummy").velocity("callout.tada", {duration: 2000});
});
supersonic.device.ready.then( function() {

    $("#dummy").velocity("callout.tada", {duration: 2000});

});

</script>

<div style="margin-top:50px;" id="dummy"> Hiiiii </div>
```

Comment: Did you include Velocity's UI Pack (veloctiy.ui.js)?

Comment: @ydaniv yes, it works perfectly fine on chrome but nothing shows up on my phone

Comment: In that case the problem is probably in your code. You'll have to provide more info.